How is a large blob transferred over HTTP without streaming?
Recently I tried to transfer a large file (3.8GB) to a server using this code that makes use of python requests library:
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    response = requests.post(url, data=f, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})

It worked! and I was able to transfer the file to the server. However, when I stepped through the code, to my surprise I found that the request did not use any streaming or chunked transfer encoding. Here is the request state just before call to conn.urlopen:
request.headers
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Content-Length': '3848008288'}
chunked
False

How is it possible for such a large file to be transferred without streaming? I have only 8GB RAM on my computer. I don't think this file can even fit in my computer memory. The server is also running locally. Can someone explain me how it works?
My follow-up question is that I also followed with another experiment in which I used multipart/form-data MIME type and in this case I am not able to transfer the file. Would like to know the difference re: how these two are handled internally.
